# Add os to grub from secon hard drive {Problem}

Tags: dual-boot

I am in troubles, my second OS doesn't appear at grub,  I installed RHEL 7.4 on a second hard drive and I runed 
sudo update-grub2 and update-grub however that commands didn't work.

I found files on second drive but it doesn't work also I try to add new file to /etc/grub.d/40_custom however so didn't appear.

Comment: Are both installs UEFI or both BIOS? Did you install boot loader of second drive's install to second drive? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thansk! I will try it.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25970821/

Comment: I had a problem with RHEL, after Reparing Grub RHEL appeared in grub but It couldn't run because secure boot forbids loading modules from hd0,gpt1/grub/x86_x64/xfs/mod

Comment: You may just need to turn UEFI secure boot off. Can you directly boot each install from UEFI boot menu? Ubuntu often needs you to add the lvm2 driver and mount any LVM partitions for its os-prober to find other installs in LVM. IF Ubuntu not LVM, it uninstalls the lvm2 driver during clean up at end of install as not needed.

Comment: You are ok, I did  that and it is OK now but now appears  a lot of partitions